# OSM xml broken?

Tags: java, xml, openstreetmap

I have downloaded the OSM world-map.
While parsing I get an Exception:

```
osm
bound
changeset
(...)
changeset
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3682; columnNumber: 140; XML-Dokumentstrukturen müssen innerhalb derselben Entity beginnen und enden.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:899)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1398)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1916)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(XMLEntityScanner.java:1187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:987)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1548)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at xxxx.web.OSMReader.main(OSMReader.java:20)
```

My code is:

```
public class OSMReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        BZip2CompressorInputStream bic = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("X:\\Medien\\Karten\\planet-200309.osm.bz2")));
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.newSAXParser().parse(bic, new DefaultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(qName);
            }
        });
        bic.close();
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that OSM is able to produce capable XML files.

The XML-File itself is much too large to confirm the problem.

Any idea how to parse the XML successfully?

### EDIT

I tried to read the lines in the xml:

```
public class OSMReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        BZip2CompressorInputStream bic = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("X:\\Medien\\Karten\\planet-200309.osm.bz2")));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bic));
        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < 3685) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (i > 3680) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        bic.close();
    }
}
```

What gives me this output:

```
 <changeset id="3678" created_at="2008-06-01T01:18:46Z" closed_at="2008-06-01T02:47:15Z" open="false" user="mawis" uid="37850" min_lat="49.1950155" min_lon="9.2284944" max_lat="49.2049970" max_lon="9.2458586" num_changes="154" comments_count="0"/>
 <changeset id="3679" created_at="2007-04-01T11:30:20Z" closed_at="2007-04-01T12:30:24Z" open="false" user="B10xxx" uid="6454" min_lat="52.
null
null
null
```

I checked the MD5 hashes and they match:

```
X:\Medien\Karten>fciv -md5 planet-200309.osm.bz2
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
4da6b47311c1b05f603542a55df2d69b planet-200309.osm.bz2

X:\Medien\Karten>
```

With the contents of https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/2020/planet-200309.osm.bz2.md5

Comment: @mmd You can download the OSM world-map at https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/2020/ It is a huge xml file telling the vectors of streets on this planet.

Comment: @mmd I do neither look for workarounds nor for alternatives. I do like to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you aware that OSM planet files have been created using parallel bzip2 and are multistream files, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29434158/3501889 and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/full - I think your code doesn't handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a `, true` to the constructor of the BZip2CompressorInputStream.

Comment: Description of the second parameter: `decompressConcatenated` - if true, decompress until the end of the input; if false, stop after the first .bz2 stream and leave the input position to point to the next byte after the .bz2 stream